# Puppeteer checking proxy returns my original IP address

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I wanted to use a proxy in Puppeteer but it only works in normal websites like google or stackoverflow but when I check a website like whatismyipaddress it doesn't work if I point it directly inside the code but it works if I searched for it but it returns my original IP without the proxy , why is that or is something wrong with my code ?

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra";
import Stealth from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth'
import { executablePath } from "puppeteer";
import useProxy from "puppeteer-page-proxy";

puppeteer.use(Stealth())
async function main(url) {

const proxy = 'http://135.181.40.86:8080';
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
    headless: false, 
    defaultViewport: null , 
    executablePath: executablePath() , 
    args: [`--proxy-server=${proxy}`] 
})

const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
await page.goto(url)


await page.waitForTimeout(10000000)
await browser.close()
}

main("https://www.whatismyipaddress.com/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the line with

```js
await page.setRequestInterception(true)
```

and your code works with [whatismyipaddress](https://www.whatismyipaddress.com/) as is, i.e. it shows the [proxy's IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcTfG.jpg).

```js
import useProxy from "puppeteer-page-proxy";
```

also isn't needed here.

and change

```js
await page.waitForTimeout(10000000)
```

to

```js
await page.waitForSelector('body');
```

as [page.waitForTimeout](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitfortimeout) is obsolete

Comment: thank you but does this error refers that there is a problem with the proxy ?

Error: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT at https://whatismyipaddress.com/

Comment: @geniar99s yes that is due to the proxy, just tested it and it isn't working for me at the moment as well. But other ones I tried yesterday are.